# Spring Framework connect to multiple data bases xml JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to connect to two data bases in using my db config file. If i define second bean for data source i have an exception for a not writable property. Which is the correct way to define two data sources ? And do i need to do something in my java classes ?

**data-source.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Here's a description, how to use jpa annotations with multiple databases, and how to configure it with `@Configuration` http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: This example is how to do it with hibernate (but i do not use it). I already find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceSecond"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplateSecond" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSecond" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```